# sequelize-auto relation issue using sequelize

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

I'm using sequelize-auto to create the models from the database. But I'm not able to use include method for the relationship. I'm getting the below error

Error: student_details_tbl (studentDetails) is not associated to user_tbl!

Here are my models and database connections.

database Connection

```
var config      =   require('./config'); 
var Sequelize   =   require('sequelize');

var db          =   new Sequelize(config.dbConn.database, config.dbConn.user, config.dbConn.password,{
    dialect     :   config.dbConn.dialect,
    host        :   config.dbConn.host,
    port        :   config.dbConn.port,
    pool        :   config.dbConn.pool,
    define      :   {
        timestamps: false
    }
});

db.sync();


db.Sequelize    =   Sequelize;

module.exports  =   db;
```

user_tbl :

```
module.exports = function(sequelize, DataTypes) {
  return sequelize.define('user_tbl', {
    id: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER(11),
      allowNull: false,
      primaryKey: true,
      autoIncrement: true
    },
    firstName: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: true
    },
    lastName: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: true
    },
    loginId: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: true
    },
    password: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: true
    },
    created: {
      type: DataTypes.DATE,
      allowNull: true,
      defaultValue: sequelize.literal('CURRENT_TIMESTAMP')
    },
    modified: {
      type: DataTypes.DATE,
      allowNull: true,
      defaultValue: sequelize.literal('CURRENT_TIMESTAMP')
    }
  }, {
    tableName: 'user_tbl'
  });
};
```

student_details_tbl :

```
module.exports = function(sequelize, DataTypes) {
  return sequelize.define('student_details_tbl', {
    id: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER(11),
      allowNull: false,
      primaryKey: true,
      autoIncrement: true
    },
    userId: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER(11),
      allowNull: true,
      references: {
        model: 'user_tbl',
        key: 'id'
      }
    },
    barcode: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER(13),
      allowNull: false
    },
    rollNumber: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: false,
      defaultValue: ''
    },
    created: {
      type: DataTypes.DATE,
      allowNull: true,
      defaultValue: sequelize.literal('CURRENT_TIMESTAMP')
    },
    modified: {
      type: DataTypes.DATE,
      allowNull: true,
      defaultValue: sequelize.literal('CURRENT_TIMESTAMP')
    }
  }, {
    tableName: 'student_details_tbl'
  });
};
```

Answer (score 1):

"Some times you may want to reference another table, without adding any constraints, or associations. In that case you can manually add the reference attributes to your schema definition, and mark the relations between them.".

So, with reference attribute you won't have your models relations created in DataBase. You should use associate in classMethods like HasOne, BelongsTo ...

http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/latest/docs/associations/

Comment: How to add that. Because of the models are created  from the database.

Comment: When i used it, i had to put it manually after generated. I think they still can't do it automaticly.

https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize-auto/issues/65

Comment: I tried to use the student_details_tbl in include, But it poitns student_details_tbl.userTblId column insteadof student_details_tbl.userId

Comment: I would say for you to remove the userId property from studeent_details and do it like this :


module.exports = function(sequelize, DataTypes) {
  return sequelize.define('student_details_tbl', {
    id: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER(11),
      allowNull: false,
      primaryKey: true,
      autoIncrement: true
    }
    ...
  }, {
    tableName: 'student_details_tbl',
     classMethods: {
        associate: function(models) {
          models.student_details_tbl.belongsTo(models.user_tbl, {foreignKey: 'userId'});
        }
      }
  });
};

Comment: but I created this from existing database using sequalize-auto. There is no option to add that. right ?

Comment: is there any way to add the class methods using db.import ?

Comment: i changed this line return sequelize.define('user_tbl', .. as return sequelize.define('user', { .. it works fine. but how ll i change it using sequalize auto /

Comment: Do you need to use the sequelize-auto all the time? In my case, i runned just one time, and made the changes to the files that i needed.

Comment: Ok. but whenever i made the changes in database i need to use sequalize-auto. so only